# How for force metapost to produce grayscale figures?

Tags: color, pdf, metapost

If I draw in metapost with parameter 0.7 white it automatically considered as colorful pdf. Is there any parameter changing it?

The story is the following:
On my job the printer prints colorful and monochrome pdf-pages in different ways. Colorful driver does not work properly, so if my black-and-white figure marked as colorful it became blue.

Comment: The default colour model is RGB, and `white` is defined to be the RGB colour `(1,1,1)`.  If you want only grey scale, then use a `numeric` instead of a `color`.  So in your case try: `draw ... withcolor 0.7`.    See p.28 of mpman

Comment: You can also try setting `defaultcolormodel := 3`

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. Maybe printer use another strange algorithm...

Comment: Are you creating an `.eps` file from MP? and then making a PDF?  Does your PDF creating tool provide any options?  What is the printer?

Comment: I compile to mps. Then open it in skim (it is a pdf viewer in MacOs) and print it from skim. The printer is Ricoh Aficio MP C4502a

Comment: When you bring up the print dialogue in Skim you should be able to set the printer features you want.  You may need to click on the box that says "PDF" to bring that tab up.  Perhaps you can choose grey scale from there?

Comment: One final thought:  you might like to make sure you have up to date drivers?  If the [Apple drivers](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1867) don't help, then [Gutenprint](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/MacOSX.php) might.

Comment: If I print with greyscale option everything is ok. But the file is already  black-and-white. Something strange here.